# Slow "Copying to tmp table" profile step

Tags: mysql, mariadb, performance, performance-tuning

I have a MariaDB (MySQL) query that uses a `DISTINCT` to get my results. The query takes about **6 seconds** to complete.

Is there any way to improve the speed of the `"Copying to tmp table" step? This is where the majority of the running time comes from.

**A few things to note:**

- The temp table is created in-memory (not on disk)
- I'd like to see if this can be improved without re-writing the query
- `fact_warehouse_inventory_change` has **~48K rows**
- `dim_date` has **~9K rows** starting from 01-01-1995 through 2020-12-31

#### QUERY

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT fact_warehouse_inventory_change.warehouse_location_id
FROM fact_warehouse_inventory_change
INNER JOIN dim_date ON
    dim_date.date >= fact_warehouse_inventory_change.row_effective_date AND
    dim_date.date <= fact_warehouse_inventory_change.row_expiration_date
```

#### EXPLAIN

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: dim_date
         type: index
possible_keys: ux_date_date_id,date,date_desc
          key: date
      key_len: 3
          ref: NULL
         rows: 9498
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: fact_warehouse_inventory_change
         type: ALL
possible_keys: row_effective_date,row_effective_date_row_expiration_date,row_expiration_date_row_effective_date_warehouse_location_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 48124
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Range checked for each record (index map: 0xC8)
```

#### TABLES

```
-- Abbreviated table definition
CREATE TABLE `dim_date` (
    `date_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `year` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `year_for_week` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `year_for_week_iso8601` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `quarter` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `month` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `week_of_year` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `week_of_month` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `week_of_year_iso8601` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `week_of_month_iso8601` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `weekday_in_month` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`date_id`, `date`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ux_date_date_id` (`date`, `date_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `date` (`date`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `date_desc` (`date`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (year(date))
(PARTITION part0 VALUES LESS THAN (2010) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part1 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part2 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part3 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part4 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part5 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part6 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part7 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part8 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part9 VALUES LESS THAN (2019) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part10 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)  */;

CREATE TABLE `fact_warehouse_inventory_change` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `warehouse_allocation_key` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `warehouse_item_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `warehouse_location_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `inventory_qty` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `reorder_qty` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `minimum_on_hand_qty` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `individual_price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `unit_of_measure_price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `row_effective_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `row_expiration_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `date_id` (`date_id`),
    INDEX `warehouse_item_id` (`warehouse_item_id`),
    INDEX `row_effective_date` (`row_effective_date`),
    INDEX `warehouse_allocation_key` (`warehouse_allocation_key`),
    INDEX `warehouse_location_id` (`warehouse_location_id`),
    INDEX `row_effective_date_row_expiration_date` (`row_effective_date`, `row_expiration_date`),
    INDEX `row_expiration_date_row_effective_date_warehouse_location_id` (`row_expiration_date`, `row_effective_date`, `warehouse_location_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=47776
;
```

#### CONFIG

```
tmp_table_size                  = 256M
max_heap_table_size             = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_open_files               = 400
innodb_io_capacity              = 400
```

Answer (score 2):

- The query is missing (after line 3) `dim_date.date_id = ...date WHERE`.  Adding that will speed it up some.  The following items assume that is present and critique the schema and query further...
- That query is an example of why dates should not be normalized.
- Do not redundantly specify `UNIQUEness` -- PK(a,b) + UNIQUE(b,a) -- change `UNIQUE` to `INDEX`.
- There is no "DESC" index, so that second `UNIQUE(date)` is redundant.  (8.0 will fix that deficiency; meanwhile *most* queries can run backwards efficiently.)
- There was no advantage, and some performance disadvantages, in `PARTITIONing` `dim_date`.
- There is a `YEAR` datatype.
- Once you have thrown away `dim_date` completely, learn the functions needed for finding `MONTH()`, etc.  And replace `date_id` with just `date`.
- Well, OK, there is a use for dim_date -- whenever you need to report on the data *and* include dates for which there is no data.  Still, `date_id` is useless, and `date` should be the PK.
- `fact_warehouse_inventory_change` currently has under 50K rows; will it grow to millions?  If so, we need to talk about creating and maintaining "Summary tables".
- There at least 2 redundant indexes in `fact_warehouse_inventory_change` -- `INDEX(a)` is redundant when you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.
- Even after un-normalizing `date`, the query will still be a full table scan.  This is because no index is useful against `date >= eff AND date <= exp`.  What percentage of rows will pass that range test?  If it is only a small fraction, then consider removing the failing rows from the table.
- Building indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql
- DW:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse
- Summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
- How much RAM do you have?  `tmp_table_size should be no more than about 1% of RAM.`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of *available* RAM.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. Good comments here. It wasn't until you brought up the dim_date indexes that I noticed some of the ridiculousness there that apparently I had left behind during testing. I have removed redundant indexes as you suggested for cleanup. You're right too regarding why dim_date is required so unfortunately, it is not going anywhere. These changes I just mentioned all help cleanup the structure, but none improve the speed unfortunately. It may simply be necessary to create a summary table as you mentioned for speed purposes unless you have any other suggestions.

Comment: I have 8GB of RAM, but am considering bumping this to 12GB. I can resize my VM as we have excess capacity available.

Comment: Was my first bullet point correct about the missing clause in the query?  Be sure to increase buffer_pool_size whenever you add RAM.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not correct. The `date_id` in the `fact_warehouse_inventory_change` table is the date that the change took place (which is the same date as `row_effective_date`, so while `date_id` technically represents the same row in `dim_date` that would be referenced by `row_effective_date`, I need an entire span of dates between `row_effective_date` and `row_expiration_date`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If all three columns (in `fact...`) were actual `DATEs`, the query would not need the other table for _this_ query.  And that would make a significance performance improvement.  If we are still confusing each other, suggest you supply a short list of rows from both tables that exemplify the issues.